# add table codefirst migration entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

A new table is not created during migration.

Migration itself seems to be created

```
public partial class _222 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ToDos",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Body = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ToDos", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "ToDos");
        }
    }
```

But when I write Update-Database table is not created.

ApplicationDbContext

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }
```

ToDos

```
public class ToDo
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

From errors in the package manager console

```
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. It is trying to create a table called AspNetRoles which already exists in the database. Since this isn't the table your migration is creating, I expect this is a previous migration that needs to be applied first. Probably this table has been manually created which is why the migration history shows the migration still needs to be applied. If it's a dev database perhaps you can remove that table and allow the migration to apply. Another workaround would be to find the applicable migration and comment out the content of the Up method. You'd need to check the schema of the existing table is correct though, in case there has been any changes.